# Why Modulo When Finding Prime Numbers

Tags: numbers, modulo

I'm trying to understand why one needs modulo operator in writing a program that finds prime numbers; I'm a student analysing some code for learning purposes, and I am confused as to why modulo is needed.

Comment: The modulo operation isn't strictly required. what is needed is a way to determine if one integer exactly divides into another and modulo is a way of doing that, but can be done without using the modulo operator explicitly. Look up sieve of Eratosthenes

Answer (score 0):

Explicit modulo isn't required. Consider an implementation of the [sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) (in C for the sake of using something):

```
int numbersThatMayBePrime[100];

memset(numbersThatMayBePrime, 0, sizeof(int)*100);

for(int c = 2; c < 100; c++)
{
    if(!numbersThatMayBePrime[c])
    {
        printf("%d\n", c);

        for(int strikeThrough = c; strikeThrough < 100; strikeThrough += c)
            numbersThatMayBePrime[strikeThrough] = -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with C; could you implement it in Java for me?

Answer (score 0):

If the modulo of n % (all numbers between n and zero) is always positive and never zero, the number is prime. 
I am trying to figure out how to code this in javascript.